# Inserting into database

Tags: java, android, sql

I have written a query to insert values into a database in Android:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + KEY_SITUATION_NAME
         + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CATEGORY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
         + KEY_LATTIUDE +" NOT NULL," + KEY_LONGITUDE + " NOT NULL," + " );");
```

However, when I execute it, an error is thrown. Can anyone point out the error in it?

Comment: what error u r getting,where is the code for insertion?

Comment: what error it throws? please post the error which is in log cat so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + KEY_SITUATION_NAME
     + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CATEGORY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
     + KEY_LATTIUDE +" INTEGER NOT NULL," + KEY_LONGITUDE + " INTEGER NOT NULL" + " );");
```

Provide a Datatype to KEY_LATITUDE and to KEY_LONGITUDE.

And also you have kept a (,) at last which was not needed...

Answer (score 0):

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + KEY_SITUATION_NAME
             + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CATEGORY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
             + KEY_LATTIUDE +" NOT NULL," + KEY_LONGITUDE + " NOT NULL);");
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct code is:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + KEY_SITUATION_NAME
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CATEGORY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_LATTIUDE +" NOT NULL," + KEY_LONGITUDE + " NOT NULL," + " )");
```